# Disable the overlap of nodes

Tags: javascript, vis.js, visnetwork

I have created visualisation using vis-network, the problem is that the nodes are overlapping one on top of the other.

[image: overlapping nodes]

I have tried changing different values of `nodeSpacing` till 1000, that didn't help
Also i have tried  setting `barnesHut.avoidOverlap` to 1 and that didn't help either,

any suggestions to fix this will be highly appreciated.

Updated options object

```
    var options = {
        interaction: {
            hover: true
        },
        manipulation: {
          enabled: true,
        },
        layout: {
            hierarchical: {
              direction: "LR",
              shakeTowards: "leaves",
              nodeSpacing: 1000,
              treeSpacing: 300,
            },
        },
        physics: {
            stabilization: {
                enabled: true, // <------ Disables animation.
                iterations: 4000
            },
            barnesHut: {
                avoidOverlap: 1
            }
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the documentation [here](https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/docs/network/layout.html) for the `layout.hierarchical.nodeSpacing` option:

> This is only for the initial layout. If you enable physics, the node distance there will be the effective node distance.

Therefore `nodeSpacing` isn't the final distance when physics is enabled. Two possible options are described below with examples.

#### nodeSpacing with Physics Disabled

The `nodeSpacing` option could be used with physics disabled. With physics disabled edges will likely overlap nodes when there are a large number of nodes. An example of this can be seen at https://jsfiddle.net/pbx8m9sk/.

#### nodeDistance with Hierarchical Repulsion Solver

As mentioned in the `solver` section of the documentation [here](https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/docs/network/physics.html) the hierarchical repulsion solver is used by default when using a hierarchical layout. When the `hierarchicalRepulsion` solver is used the `nodeDistance` option can be used to control the distance between the nodes.

For example:

```js
var options = {
  physics: {
    hierarchicalRepulsion: {
      nodeDistance: 300,
    }
  }
};
```

Snippet using hierarchical repulsion solver with node distance set is below. You would likely want to adjust the `nodeDistance` and could adjust other hierarchicalRepulsion [options](https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/docs/network/physics.html), depending on the data.

```js
// Setup initial nodes / edges
const nodes = [
  {id: 1, label: '1'},
  {id: 2, label: '2'},
  {id: 3, label: '3'},
  {id: 4, label: '4'},
  {id: 5, label: '5'},
  {id: 6, label: '6'},
  {id: 7, label: '7'},
  {id: 8, label: '8'},
  {id: 9, label: '9'},
  {id: 10, label: '10'},
  {id: 11, label: '11'},
];
const edges = [
 {from: 1, to: 2},
 {from: 2, to: 3},
 {from: 2, to: 4},
 {from: 2, to: 5},
 {from: 2, to: 6},
 {from: 2, to: 7},
 {from: 2, to: 8},
 {from: 2, to: 9},
 {from: 2, to: 10},
 {from: 2, to: 11},
];

// Add a number nodes / edges
const nodesToAdd = 200;
for (let i = 12; i < 12 + nodesToAdd; i++){
  nodes.push({id: i, label: `${i}`});
  edges.push({from: 11, to: i});
}

var data = {
  nodes: nodes,
  edges: edges,
};
// create a network
var container = document.getElementById("mynetwork");
var options = {
  interaction: {
    hover: true
  },
  manipulation: {
    enabled: true
  },
  nodes: {
    shape: 'dot',
  },

  layout: {
    hierarchical: { },
  },
  physics: {
    hierarchicalRepulsion: {
      nodeDistance: 300,
    }
  },
       
};
var network = new vis.Network(container, data, options);
```

```css
#mynetwork {
  width: 100%;
  height: 170px;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/standalone/umd/vis-network.min.js"></script>
<div id="mynetwork"></div>
```